# Highlighting Solr search results with bin/post and managed schema

Tags: solr, highlighting

I've got Solr 6.6.1 installed. I run bin/post to fetch and index some documents into a new core. I'd like to add a text field and highlight on that field. I notice that in server/solr/myCore/conf that there is a file, managed-schema, with a warning that tells me not to edit the file.

What's the supported way to use bin/post AND enable highlighting on a text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr implicitly uses a `ManagedIndexSchemaFactory`, which is by default "mutable" and keeps schema information in a managed-schema file.

You have several choices:

1. Go back to `<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>`, so you will be able to change schema file manually.
2. Stay with managed Schema API and just modification [operations via HTTP](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html#SchemaAPI-ModifytheSchema) to add new field, which you will use for highlighting.

I would recommend to stick with #2, but it's totally up to you. [Official documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/highlighting.html#Highlighting-SchemaOptionsandPerformanceConsiderations) will help you to choose which schema options for your text fields you need to get the best out of highlighting.

Comment: Thanks. There is a catch-all _ text _ field in the managed schema, copied from "*". When I enable highlighting and specify _ text _ as the highlight field I don't see _ text _ in the response. I'll dig a bit more into that and create a new question if I can't figure this out.

Comment: @Sol sounds perfect to me, feel free to post the link to the question under this comment

Comment: The _ text _ field is indexed but it's not stored so it's not returned in results. I've updated the schema to make it a stored field, deleted all of the records, re-added them, and now I see the _ text _ field in the index. Yay! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It's also safe to edit the managed schema file - as long as you're careful - i.e. stop Solr first (or know that nothing will rewrite the file before you reload the core).